# ipython: change PageDown/PageUp to move back/forward through command history

Tags: python, ipython, prompt-toolkit

In my shell (`zsh`) or in `python`, I can go backward through command history by pressing <kbd>PageDown</kbd>, and I can go forward by pressing <kbd>PageUp</kbd>.

But in `ipython`, these shortcuts are reversed.

Where are these shortcuts defined for `ipython`, and how can I reverse them back, so that

<kbd>PageDown</kbd> goes back in history, and <kbd>PageUp</kbd> goes forward in history?

I am using `ipython3` version `5.8.0` on Debian 10.

Comment: what is you  python version.

Comment: @Chandan - `python 3.7.3`

Comment: what is your os?

Comment: Debian 10 @Chandan

Comment: try adding these bindings in `ipythonrc` file - `readline_parse_and_bind "\e[5~": history-search-backward`, `readline_parse_and_bind "\e[6~": history-search-forward`

Comment: @Chandan - that has no effect. I am not even sure the file ipythonrc is used anymore: 
 https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21793051/ipython-does-not-read-inputrc

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create script in `~/.ipython/profile_default/startup` directory with any name ending with extension `.py` or `.ipy`

For example i created `history_keybindings.py` and put it inside `~/.ipython/profile_default/startup` directory

```py
from IPython import get_ipython
from IPython.terminal.shortcuts import previous_history_or_previous_completion, next_history_or_next_completion
from prompt_toolkit.keys import Keys
from prompt_toolkit.filters import HasSelection

ip = get_ipython()

registry = None

if (getattr(ip, 'pt_app', None)):
   # for IPython versions 7.x
   registry = ip.pt_app.key_bindings
elif (getattr(ip, 'pt_cli', None)):
   # for IPython versions 5.x
   registry = ip.pt_cli.application.key_bindings_registry

if registry:
   registry.add_binding(Keys.PageUp, filter=(~HasSelection()))(previous_history_or_previous_completion)
   registry.add_binding(Keys.PageDown, filter=(~HasSelection()))(next_history_or_next_completion)
```

**Note:** For more info check [here](https://ipython.readthedocs.io/en/5.x/config/details.html#keyboard-shortcuts)

Comment: still does not work: `AttributeError: 'CommandLineInterface' object has no attribute 'key_bindings'`

Comment: @400theCat i have updated answer please check again

Answer (score 1):

In IPython version 5.x, this is mentioned in the documentation: [Specific config details — IPython 5.11.0.dev documentation](https://ipython.readthedocs.io/en/5.x/config/details.html#keyboard-shortcuts)

To get the function to bind to, see `key_binding/bindings/basic.py`: The default is

```py
handle("pageup", filter=~has_selection)(get_by_name("previous-history"))
handle("pagedown", filter=~has_selection)(get_by_name("next-history"))
```

So, put this code in a [startup file](https://ipython.readthedocs.io/en/latest/interactive/tutorial.html#startup-files):

```py
from IPython import get_ipython
from prompt_toolkit.filters import HasSelection
from prompt_toolkit.keys import Keys
from prompt_toolkit.key_binding.bindings.named_commands import get_by_name

registry = get_ipython().pt_cli.application.key_bindings_registry
registry.add_binding(Keys.PageUp, filter=~HasSelection())(get_by_name("next-history"))
registry.add_binding(Keys.PageDown, filter=~HasSelection())(get_by_name("previous-history"))
```

On newer IPython versions (such as 7.19.0) replace the `registry = ...` line with

```py
registry = get_ipython().pt_app.key_bindings
```

Reference: [Specific config details — IPython 7.19.0 documentation](https://ipython.readthedocs.io/en/7.19.0/config/details.html#keyboard-shortcuts)

Comment: Possibly related: [1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38443907/how-does-one-set-specific-vim-bindings-in-ipython-5-0-0) [2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30014267/custom-keybindings-for-ipython-terminal) [3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42828946/is-there-any-way-to-replace-the-exists-default-key-bindings-in-ipython-vi-mode)  [4](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21793051/ipython-does-not-read-inputrc) [5](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38659721/ipython-5-0-and-key-bindings-in-console)

Comment: I get this error: `AttributeError: 'TerminalInteractiveShell' object has no attribute 'pt_app'`